# Pandas to_csv should suppress exponential

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a dataframe of datatype object and while writing to CSV,it's getting converted to exponential and
I want to retain the value as it is.I tried everything like

```
pd.set_option('display.precision',12)
```

works only if I print the column ..But when I write it to csv,its getting converted to exponential.Result should be applied to all the columns that are getting converted to exponential

Input Looks as follows

```
EXTERNAL_AUTHOR_ID
1234260000000000000
816425000000000000
1703362346
1234260000000000000
1025974896
1025974896
1025974896
1252600000000000000
1156200000000000000
1118580000000000000
888878000000000000
166473676
1425348680
1212230000000000000
1196320000000000000
236781415
1049950000000000000
481432116
24366583
1240650000000000000
1240650000000000000
1224370000000000000
1234260000000000000
816425000000000000
1703362346
1234260000000000000
1025974896
1025974896
1025974896
1252600000000000000
1156200000000000000
1118580000000000000
888878000000000000
166473676
1425348680
1212230000000000000
1196320000000000000
236781415
1049950000000000000
481432116
24366583
1240650000000000000
1240650000000000000
1224370000000000000
```

Output looks as follows

```
EXTERNAL_AUTHOR_ID
1.23426e+18
8.16425e+17
1703362346.0
1.23426e+18
1025974896.0
1025974896.0
1025974896.0
1.2526e+18
1.1562e+18
1.11858e+18
8.88878e+17
166473676.0
1425348680.0
1.21223e+18
1.19632e+18
236781415.0
1.04995e+18
481432116.0
24366583.0
1.24065e+18
1.24065e+18
1.22437e+18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you set is a display precision, i.e. what is displayed on the screen. For writing to file with `to_csv` use `float_format` option:

```
df.to_csv('your.csv', sep=',', float_format='%f')
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randn(10,2) * 10**18 # produced exponential notation 
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df.to_csv('your.csv', sep=',', float_format='%f')
```

An alternative, as requested by the OP, is to print everything in the verbatim format by assigning data type of respective columns to `str`.

Comment: @AnirudhS Can you double-check that? Make sure to open the file in a text editor, nothing more advanced (like spreadsheet program) that can apply its own formatting. I just checked this on pandas 1.0.3 and it works just fine. What's your version?

Comment: Hi @Lukasz..I added the precision  and float format.And when I open the file the its giving output as 1425348680.0 1.19632e+18 1.21223e+18

Comment: @AnirudhS Now you have it in float format notation - is this what you were aiming at? You can further modify the precision with `%f` formatter or change to integers (should this be more fitting).

Comment: I just want to retain the original value from the input file what i'm getting.Instead this is getting converted to exponential

Comment: And I have changed float_format='%f' this to float_format='%30f' and not getting the desired output and the datatype of that column is object

Comment: I don't know what is your "desired output" - it'd help a good deal if you could share it, and the data. Also, note that your `EXTERNAL_AUTHOR_ID` is likely outside int64 range, hence float data type.

Comment: I just want to output EXTERNAL_AUTHOR_ID from input file to output file as it is.But thats not happening

Comment: Again, `EXTERNAL_AUTHOR_ID` is likely a float in your computer memory. If you'd like all floats in the dataframe to be treated as integers, you can specify "%d" format. If you need more nuanced formatting, convert your data to strings, modify them to your liking and then save to a CSV.

Comment: @AnirudhS ... or you can write your own method to save to CSV, with e.g. `csv` module. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @AnirudhS So how about using the `float_format='%d'` that I mentioned before?

Comment: Its solved thanks for the help..while read the csv i read all the columns as string and its working properly..dtype=str

Comment: @AnirudhS Good to hear that. I will edit my answer to reflect what worked in the end. If you could accept the answer, that would be helpful.